# Getting permission for accessing an existing file in setup created using Inno Setup

Tags: c#, windows-installer, inno-setup, file-access

I am a new C# programmer. I made a setup file of an application in Inno setup, but when I use this application after installation, the application crashes when it tries to access (read) an existing folder in the computer (which the user has permission to access otherwise). **This folder does not contain any program file, or logs. It just contains some media files which are already in the computer.**

I saw the Inno script format, but it shows only how to give permission to access program files/folders only, what about the files which  are already there in the computer? Shouldn't the application should have access to files which the user (who installed it)has access to ?

Comment: What specific error message does the application display?

Comment: Does the app crash if it is launched manually? Are you sure there is no need to exec it as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

To set permissions on existing files or folders, you can use the Windows cacls command in the `[Run]` section.

```
Filename: "{sys}\cacls.exe"; Parameters: """C:\My Folder\My File.ext"" /t /e /g ""Everyone"":f ""Power Users"":f ""Users"":f ""Authenticated Users"":f "; StatusMsg: "Configuring Windows settings..."; Flags: runhidden
```

Type cacls /? at a command prompt for all available switches and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I used

**"Permissions: users-modify"** in [Dirs] section.